# Parental Controls in OSX Mac Lab

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, game-maker

I administer a couple of Mac labs at our school. (OSX Yosemite)
The students use these computers by logging into a local shared account that is limited by Parental Controls.

For the most part this works fine, but our IST students are now creating new applications using things like Game Maker by Yoyo etc. When a student app is created, it cannot be run unless it is allowed via Parental Controls. Even if Allow Always is set on a debug version of the app, it will not run the second time as the signature of the file changes each time it is run.

Are there any workarounds that anybody has used to allow these sorts of app builders run under Parental Controls?